# Angular 2/4 npm install issue

Tags: node.js, angular

When i try to to install angular via npm i get this error message:

npm install -g @angular/cli

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\acorn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\acorn' -> 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.acorn.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-26T15_20_28_022Z-debug.log
```

current setup:

node -v
v6.11.1

npm -v
5.3.0

Comment: i'd suggest reinstall node and npm
then try again

Comment: And also after reinstalling, restart your machine once. One question: where are you running this command (at which path)?

Comment: Looks like windoze...try running from an eleveted (admin) command prompt

Comment: i tried to install it with git bash, i also tried via command prompt.

Comment: reinstalling node doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

VOILA!! I found the answer. Actually i can't claim that is a real answer to the problem but it worked damn well. So what i did is, i ran bash as administrator (i did this many times before but didn't worked), and i did next:

```
$npm cache verify (to see what will happen after i deleted some stuff, uncompleted angular package in node_modules directory for example)

$npm update ( update all outdated local packages )
$npm update -g ( update global packages )

$npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Maybe running bush as administrator wasn't necessary, maybe just npm update was enough. Anyway, i hope this solution will be helpful to someone.